# why biased notation use -(2^(N-1-1) as oﬀset ? why not use -2^(N-1)?

Tags: numbers, computer-science

IEEE floating point use -127 as offset. If we use -128, it seems more convenient that we can just remove the first bit of 8 bit exponent.

My English is poor, please don't mind it. :)

Comment: I am not entirely sure what your question actually is? Single-precision floating point has an exponent range from -126 to 127, for a total of 254 different exponents (with the values 0 and 255 having special meanings).

Comment: I think the question is, why 127 is used as exponent bias instead of 128.